# crossfilter.js & dc.js : Is there a limitation to number of dimensions and facts to be used?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter, large-data

Using crossfilter.js, we obtain crossfiltered data. But when building dimensions and groups/facts around this crossfiltered data, is there a limitation to the number of dimensions / facts that can be built? Also, is there a limitation to number of groups/facts that can be built, around one dimension?

Comment: Why do expect it to have limitations? Have you tried large numbers and got notable slowdowns?

Comment: @Bergi : Yes, half the times it's at it's slowest speed and half the times, it breaks. Trying to use 9 groups/facts on 1 dimension. Infact, I have shortlisted to 9, it would be great to know if I can use more than 16???

Answer (score 0):

There is a hard limit on the number of dimensions, see [dimension in the crossfilter documentation](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension).

I don't think there is any limit to the number of groups. However, I'd be surprised if you really want 9 different groups on one dimension. The group has to follow the same order as its dimension, so there usually are only a few ways to break up the key-space.

Perhaps you are looking for a reduction function that produces multiple reduced values? Take a look at the [annotated source for the stock example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html); `yearlyPerformanceGroup` produces about 6 metrics on a single group.